# Clarification around creating / destroying caches

Tags: gemfire, geode

I'm trying to understand how the lifecycles of caches and regions are managed for the client-server model.  I see that RegionFactory has a createRegion(String name) method.  Does this handle region lifecycles on the servers or just create an instance of the Region class associated with a region on the servers?  If I want multiple clients to access the same region, can they just call RegionFactory.createRegion() with the same region name?  What if I want to create and destroy regions programmatically from the client?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this handle region lifecycles on the servers or just create an instance of the Region class associated with a region on the servers?

It just creates a Region instance on the client, you will have use cache.xml or gfsh to create the region on the server.

> If I want multiple clients to access the same region, can they just call RegionFactory.createRegion() with the same region name?

Yes.

> What if I want to create and destroy regions programmatically from the client?

You could use [Function execution](http://geode-docs.cfapps.io/docs/developing/function_exec/chapter_overview.html) to create a region programmatically from a client.